# how to set maxlength for span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have on screen numeric keypad, i am displaying the entered digits in an span, i want to set the max limit to 4 digits only, how can i set the max length for the span? please find the HTML and Javascript.

HTML

```
<section id="app" class="numberpad">
    <section id="display" class="semi">
    <div class="semi mten">
      <span id="numerals"></span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <ul id="keypad" class="semi">
    <li id="one" class="key" role="button"><span class="number">1</span></li>
    <li id="two" class="key" role="button"><span class="number">2</span></li>
    <li id="three" class="key" role="button"><span class="number">3</span></li>
    <li id="four" class="key" role="button"><span class="number">4</span></li>
    <li id="five" class="key" role="button"><span class="number">5</span></li>
    <li id="six" class="key" role="button"><span class="number">6</span></li>
    <li id="seven" class="key" role="button"><span class="number">7</span></li>
    <li id="eight" class="key" role="button"><span class="number">8</span></li>
    <li id="nine" class="key" role="button"><span class="number">9</span></li>
    <li id="dot"><span class="number">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li id="zero" class="key" role="button"><span class="number">0</span></li>
    <li id="back" role="button"><span class="number">X</span></li>
  </ul>          
</section>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

  function reflow(){
    //adding reflow to allow the DOM to process the removeClass before calling the addClass, which insures that the css key-frame animation fires. This is an adaptation of a vaniall JS trick from Chris Coyier https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation
    $('#numerals').width($('#numerals').width());
  }

  function jiggle(){
    $('#numerals').removeClass('jiggle');
    reflow();
    $('#numerals').addClass('jiggle');
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.key', function(){  
    var content = $(this).find('span').html();

    function add(){
      $('#numerals').append('<span class="numeral">' + content + '</span>');
      reflow();
      $('.numeral').last().addClass('displayed');
    }

    if(!$(this).parent().parent().hasClass('numberpad')){
        if($('.numeral').length < 6){
          if(($('.numeral').length == 0) && (content == '0' || content == '.')){
            jiggle();
          } else if(($('.numeral').length == 0) && (content !== '0' || content !== '.')){
              $('#numerals').find('span').addClass('hide');
                setTimeout(
                function() 
                {
                  $('.hide').hide();
                  add();
                }, 150);
              } else if (content == '.'){
                add();
              } else if($('.numeral').last().hasClass('decimals')){
                add();
              } else {
                add();
                if(!$(this).parent().parent().hasClass('numberpad')){
                    //resize();
                }
              }
        } else if ($('.numeral').length == 6 && content == '.'){
          decimal();
        } else if (($('.numeral').length == 7 || $('.numeral').length == 6) && $('.numeral').last().hasClass('decimals')){
          decimalAdd();
        } else if ($('.numeral').length == 0){
          $('#numerals').append('<span class="numeral">0</span>');
          $('.numeral').last().addClass('displayed');
        } else {
          jiggle();
        }
      }else{
        if(($('.numeral').length == 0) && (content == '0' || content == '.')){
                jiggle();
            } else if(($('.numeral').length == 0) && (content !== '0' || content !== '.')){
                $('#numerals').find('span').addClass('hide');
                setTimeout(
                function() 
                {
                    $('.hide').hide();
                  add();
                }, 150);
            } else if (content == '.'){
                decimal();
            } else if($('.numeral').last().hasClass('decimals')){
                decimalAdd();
            } else {
                add();
                if(!$(this).parent().parent().hasClass('numberpad')){
                    //resize();
                }
            }
      }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#back', function(){  
    if($('.numeral').length > 0){       
      $('.numeral').last().remove();    
      //jiggle();
    }
    if($('.numeral').last().hasClass('decimals')){
        alert(1);
        $('.numeral').last().remove(); 
    }

  });

  function move(direction){

    var u = $('#user-info'),
    h = $('#history-info'),
    a = $('#app-container'),
    w = $('#app-container').width(),
    uPos = u.css('left'),
    uPos = parseInt(uPos),
    hPos = h.css('left'),
    hPos = parseInt(hPos),
    aPos = a.css('left'),
    aPos = parseInt(aPos);

    if(direction == 'left'){
      u.css('left', uPos + w);
      h.css('left', hPos + w);
      a.css('left', aPos + w).toggleClass('greyed');
    } else if(direction == 'right') {
      u.css('left', uPos - w);
      h.css('left', hPos - w);
      a.css('left', aPos - w).toggleClass('greyed');
    }
  }

  $(document).on('click', '#user, #back-left', function(){  
    move('left');
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#history, #back-right', function(){  
    move('right');
  });

  //resize();
});
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here, much of which doesn't seem relevant to the problem.Please remove all that is not relevant. What is or isn't working? Your problem statement makes no reference to the actual code. Have a read through [ask] and [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)